# UEFI - How to improve graphics's performance?

Tags: multithreading, graphics, rendering, uefi, gnu-efi

I am trying to draw a cursor with GOP. Cursor drawing happens in while loop.

My file where GOP located: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neifcwzow4WLGId7LRCzEFx5n43narDi/view?usp=sharing

```
        /*...OTHER CODE...*/
        RunGraphics(...); //CLEAR SCREEN
        setCursorPosition(&cursor, (UINT32)(Info->HorizontalResolution/2), (UINT32)(Info->VerticalResolution/2));
    
        while (1)
            {
                UINTN index;
                Status = gBS->WaitForEvent(2, &Events, &index);
        
                // INDEX 1 IS KEYBOARD MESSAGE
                if (index == 1)
                {
                    Status = gST->ConIn->ReadKeyStroke(gST->ConIn, &Key);
        
                    if ((UINTN)Key.ScanCode == SCAN_ESC)
                    {
                        if(ESC_KEY_DOWN_COUNT == 0)
                        {
                            SystemTable->ConIn->Reset(SystemTable->ConIn, FALSE);
                            SystemTable->RuntimeServices->ResetSystem(EfiResetShutdown, EFI_SUCCESS, 0, NULL);
                            return EFI_SUCCESS;
                        }
                        ESC_KEY_DOWN_COUNT--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ESC_KEY_DOWN_COUNT = 2;
                        Print(L"%c", Key.UnicodeChar);
        
                    }
                }
                else if (index == 0)
                {
                    Status = mouse->GetState(mouse, &State);
        
                    Print(L"X:%d Y:%d Z:%d L:%d R:%d\n",
                        State.RelativeMovementX,
                        State.RelativeMovementY,
                        State.RelativeMovementZ,
                        State.LeftButton,
                        State.RightButton
                    );
        
                    setCursorPosition(&cursor, cursor.Position.X + State.RelativeMovementX, cursor.Position.Y + State.RelativeMovementY, info->HorizontalResolution, info->VerticalResolution);

DrawCursorClassic(cursor.Position.X,cursor.Position.Y,255,255,255 /*RGB*/);
//RUNS VERY LAGGY.
        
                }
            }
```

What should I do to improve my performance or what I did wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried it without printing the debug messages to the screen?

Comment: Alright, after reviewing the code I realized that while copying some codes from my RunGraphics function, I forgot and left  gBS->Stall(500 * 1000); like that. So that 500 * 1000 = 500ms for redrawing. I changed it to something like 10ms. That should be lesser for better results. My issue is gone.